# pyqt application debugging does not work in eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pyqt4, pydev

I am currently writing my first pyqt application using eclipse. I have used qt designer to develop the main window gui and i am able to run it without problems in eclipse.

I noticed however that when I try to debug it in eclipse that this doesn't work... It seems to go wrong on the first qt related line of code: 
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

As a test I used the same code and debugged it with IDLE (python GUI) and then everything is ok (I can set breakpoints and step through the code).

I did already add the location of PyQt to the python path of PyDev (c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4) in the external libraries section, but this doesn't seem to fix the issue. The debugger always terminates with exit value -1073740771.

I tried to tackle the issue using the following helloPython code :

```
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class HelloPython(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(HelloPython, self).__init__(parent)
       helloLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Say Hello To PyQT!")       
       helloLineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

       mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
       mainLayout.addWidget(helloLabel, 0, 0)
       mainLayout.addWidget(helloLineEdit, 0, 1)

       self.setLayout(mainLayout)
       self.setWindowTitle("My Python App")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    helloPythonWidget = HelloPython()
    helloPythonWidget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The regular run did already work in eclipse using pydev. It is only when I switch to debug mode that it doesn't seem to work...

I did compare both the PATH and PYTHONPATH and the PATH environmnet variable was the same for IDLE and pydev.

There were two differences in the PYTHONPATH : 
1.the order of the directories 
2.location of debugger (which makes sense as we use different debuggers)

PYTHONPATH

in IDLE :

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\35gs\Workspace\test_pyqt
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\python27
C:\python27\DLLs
C:\python27\lib
C:\python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\python27\lib\plat-win
C:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

in pydev

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse-cpp-kepler-SR1-win32-x86_64\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.0.0.201504132356\pysrc
C:\Users\35gs\Workspace\test_pyqt
C:\Users\35gs\Workspace\test_pyqt
C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip
C:\python27
C:\python27\DLLs
C:\python27\Lib\site-packages
C:\python27\lib
C:\python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\python27\lib\plat-win
```

PATH

in IDLE:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BitScope
C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\WindRiver\diab\5.8.0.0\WIN32\bin
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\python27
```

in pydev:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\BitScope
C:\Program Files (x86)\CheckPoint\Endpoint Security\Endpoint Common\bin
C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4
C:\Python27\Scripts
C:\WindRiver\diab\5.8.0.0\WIN32\bin
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\system32
C:\python27
```

Version of Python : 2.7.10

Version of Eclipse : Kepler Service Release 1

Version of pydev : 4.0.0

version of SIP : 4.18.1

version of PyQT4 : 4.8.7

Answer (score 0):

It does work fine for me here (both in PyQt4 and PyQt5), so, it's probably something in your configuration...

One note:

Don't add the folder `site-packages\PyQt4` to the PYTHONPATH. If you're importing as `import PyQt4`, only the parent folder should be in the PYTHONPATH (i.e.: `site-packages` in your case).

Some notes on how to tackle the issue:

1. If the simple hello doesn't work, try to work on that first.
2. Try to make the `regular` run (just F9 with the focus on the editor) before the `debug` run (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html for more details on running a module).
3. Print the PYTHONPATH on the case that works and in the case that doesn't work and make sure that you update your interpreter/project configuration so that it's the same (see: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html and http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for how to change those configurations).

   i.e.: run: `import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)))` in both and compare the results.
4. If it's still a no-go, try to compare the environment variables on both cases (mainly `PATH` on Windows, `LD_LYBRARY_PATH` on Linux and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Mac).

   i.e.: run: `print('\n'.join(sorted(os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep))))` where it works and compare with what you have in PyDev.

If it still didn't work, please give more details on your actual example along with your python version and the info on your PYTHONPATH and PATH (with the prints from items 3 and 4 above) as it may be related to that.